# How to prefix a url with another url in a web browser using a bookmarklet?

Tags: bookmarklet, url-rewriting

There's a web service called outline.com. You paste urls into that website and it reloads the page in a neat formatting without the additional junk from the original page. Another method is to prefix the url of whatever website you're on with 'outline.com/'.

I'd like to know if I can have a bookmark(let) that will do this for me automatically.

E.g. if I'm on `http:www.testsite.com`, clicking on the bookmark should create `outline.com/http:www.testsite.com`.

I am using the latest post-Mojave-update Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bookmarklet in Firefox for Deslidifier, which operates essentially as you describe:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://deslide.clusterfake.net?o=html_table&u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));})()
```

Based on that, this should work for you with Outline, unless Safari bookmarklets work significantly differently from Firefox's:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://outline.com/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href));})()
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks, but it doesn't work. For `http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2018/11/feature_20_dreamcast_games_wed_love_to_see_on_nintendo_switch`, when I click on the bookmarklet a new tab opens (which shouldn't happen) and I get this url: `http://www.nintendolife.com/www.outline.com/http%3A/www.nintendolife.com/news/2018/11/feature_20_dreamcast_games_wed_love_to_see_on_nintendo_switch`

Comment: Hey. I found the answer on another website and I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden somewhere on the internet I found the answer:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bwindow.location.href %3D 'https%3A%2F%2Foutline.com%2F' %2B window.location.href%7D)()
```

Works like a gem.